# Remove the second nearest <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:-

```
<tr>
<td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><span class="ms-h3 ms-standardheader" id="ProjectETA">
<nobr>Project ETA</nobr>
    </span></td>
<td valign="top" width="350px" class="ms-formbody">
<span dir="none">
<table id="ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldTopTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>


<tr><td class="ms-dtinput">
<label for="ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldDate" style="display:none">ProjectETA Date</label>
<input type="text" value="20/03/2020" maxlength="45" id="ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldDate" title="Project ETA" class="ms-input" autopostback="0">
</td>
<td class="ms-dtinput"><a href="#" onclick="clickDatePicker('ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldDate', '\u002fsites\u002fSSC\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fiframe.aspx?cal=1&amp;lcid=2057&amp;langid=1033&amp;tz=03:59:59.9998631&amp;ww=0111110&amp;fdow=1&amp;fwoy=2&amp;hj=0&amp;swn=false&amp;minjday=109207&amp;maxjday=2666269&amp;date=', '20/03/2020', event); return false;"><img id="ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/calendar_25.gif?rev=47" border="0" alt="Select a date from the calendar." data-themekey="#"></a></td><td><iframe id="ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerFrame" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=47" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="display:none; position:absolute; width:200px; z-index:101;" title="Select a date from the calendar."></iframe></td></tr></tbody></table></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

i wrote the following to remove the second nearest `<tr>` `$("input[id^='ProjectETA_']").closest('tr').closest('tr').remove();`, but this removed the nearest `tr` and not the second nearest `tr`. any advice?

Comment: @AndrewL64 i just added sample of the code, yes i want to remove the parent tr of the nearest tr

Comment: @CertainPerformance i just added sample of the code, yes i want to remove the parent tr of the nearest tr

Comment: You are wrapping a tr element within another tr element. Do you want to remove the parent tr?

Comment: `i want to remove the parent tr of the nearest tr` -- I don't understand. Technically, the nearest tr is the parent tr itself.

Comment: @AndrewL64 ok i posted the full code/markup

Comment: You are targeting an input and based on that you want to remove closest tr related to the input ? Is there any dynamic content involved ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok i posted the full code/markup

Comment: @Novakinify not the nearest <tr>, i want to remove the second nearest which is the first tr in my case

Comment: The only valid child tag a `<tr>` may have are `<td>` or `<th>`. Any other type of tag breaks expected behavior of a valid `<table>` structure. Simply, don't expect a `<tr>` to behave as a `<tr>` if it's contents are invalid. BTW because of their initial state of being out of the flow of the DOM  `<script>` and `<template>` tags are also valid but not relevant in addressing this particular issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.closest` will return the *current element* if it matches the selector:

```js
console.log(inner.closest('div'));
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to navigate up one element in order to be able to call `.closest` again:

```
$("input[id^='ProjectETA_']").closest('tr').parent().closest('tr').remove()
```

```js
$("input[id^='ProjectETA_']").closest('tr').parent().closest('tr').remove();
console.log($('table tr').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><span class="ms-h3 ms-standardheader" id="ProjectETA">
        <nobr>Project ETA</nobr>
      </span></td>
    <td valign="top" width="350px" class="ms-formbody">
      <span dir="none">
        <table id="ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldTopTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="ms-dtinput">
                <label for="ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldDate" style="display:none">ProjectETA Date</label>
                <input type="text" value="20/03/2020" maxlength="45" id="ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldDate" title="Project ETA" class="ms-input" autopostback="0">
              </td>
              <td class="ms-dtinput"><a href="#" onclick="clickDatePicker('ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldDate', '\u002fsites\u002fSSC\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fiframe.aspx?cal=1&amp;lcid=2057&amp;langid=1033&amp;tz=03:59:59.9998631&amp;ww=0111110&amp;fdow=1&amp;fwoy=2&amp;hj=0&amp;swn=false&amp;minjday=109207&amp;maxjday=2666269&amp;date=', '20/03/2020', event); return false;"><img id="ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/calendar_25.gif?rev=47" border="0" alt="Select a date from the calendar." data-themekey="#"></a></td>
              <td><iframe id="ProjectETA_dc965d26-95ca-480a-9a5c-f671f34e37ed_$DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerFrame" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=47" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="display:none; position:absolute; width:200px; z-index:101;" title="Select a date from the calendar."></iframe></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @testtest `.closest` is not supported on IE, so consider using a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill)

Comment: @MichalisGarganourakis He's using jQuery - `.closest` is a jQuery method that doesn't require a particular browser version. (`.closest` also happens to be a DOM method which works nearly the same way, but compatibility with the DOM method isn't needed)

Comment: Oohh, just noticed that :) Apologies for any confusion.